# Having trouble saving an element into an array inside another objec

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, element

Trouble saving element in array inside an element using Node and Mongoose

I tried creating a new element, then pushing it inside an array in another element. however, it doesn't save. So, anytime the POST request finishes, the array is empty.

I only code as a hobby and probably have many errors. Also this is my first question here so be gentle :P

Thank you!

```js
app.post("/addVisit", function(req, res) {
  const newVisit = new Visit({
    CC: req.body.CC,
    history: req.body.history,
    physical: req.body.physical,
    tests: req.body.tests,
    DD: req.body.DD,
    treatment: req.body.treatment,
    date: Date(),
    doctor: currentUser
  });
  console.log("A new visit for " + req.body.petName + " " + newVisit);

  User.findOne({
      email: req.body.email
    })
    .then(function(item) {
      for (let i = 0; i < item.pets.length; i++) {
        if (item.pets[i].name == req.body.petName) {
          console.log("the one visit " + newVisit)
          item.pets[i].clinicVisits.push(newVisit);
          console.log("visit pushed");
          console.log("ALL visits " + item.pets[i].clinicVisits);
          item.save();
        }
      }
      console.log("was saved");
    })
  res.render("homeAdmin");
});
```

Comment: What is your schema for `User`?  How is `Visit` defined?

Answer (score 0):

*note: I haven't tested this solution*

I'm guessing your document looks something like this

```js
{
  email: "email@domain.com",
  pets: [
    { name: "Kanye", clinicVists: [] },
    { name: "West", clinicVists: [] },
  ],
}
```

then you might be able to push to a specific pet using this method

```js
    User.findOneAndUpdate({
        email: req.body.email,
        'pets.name': req.body.petName
      }, {
        $push: {
            'pets.$.clinicVisits': newVisit
        }
      })
      .then(function(err, doc) {
        console.log(doc);
      })
```

if that still doesnt work, perhaps you need to do `newVisit.save()`

---

#### References

**[$push](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)**

[**$elemMatch**](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#single-query-condition)

[**$ (update)**](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#---update-)